# Subclipse synchronisation history?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

In Eclipse (subclipse), is there a way to see the *synchronisation* history - i.e. not the individual files/directories history, but an history of

- when synchronisation was performed,
- what was synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say "no".

Maybe you could glean some of this info from Eclipse's log files. During synchronization, the individual SVN commands and results (such as `U file.txt`) are displayed in the console view, but I doubt that it gets saved anywhere, at least not by default.

You might also find something interesting in the HTTP access logs of the web server that hosts the repository.